# CKQuery, how to fetch all Fields from Record?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have worked out how to search my CKrecord and display the string from one field only with the code below.

I have a few questions..( i am new to this )

1. can i search and it not be case sensitive?
2. How can I search ALL fields in the record and then display all of the fields on a match?

I am making a reference app, so you can search, for example, BBC1, and all things that relate to BBC1 (i.e. in that recordID) display.

[Dashboard.jpg showing Record and Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mYLK.png)

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit
import MobileCoreServices

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var addressField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var commentsField: UITextView!

    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()

    var publicDatabase: CKDatabase?
    var currentRecord: CKRecord?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        publicDatabase = container.publicCloudDatabase
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBAction func performQuery(sender: AnyObject) {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "serviceName = %@", addressField.text!)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "SystemFields", predicate: predicate)
        publicDatabase?.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: ({results, error in
            if(error != nil) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.notifyUser("Cloud Access Error",
                        message: error!.localizedDescription)
                }
            } else {
                if results!.count > 0 {
                    let record = results![0]
                    self.currentRecord = record

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.commentsField.text = record.objectForKey("Location") as! String
                    }
                } else { dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.notifyUser("No Match Found",
                        message: "No record matching the address was found")
                    }
                }
            }
        }))
    }

    func notifyUser(title: String, message: String) -> Void
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title,
                                      message: message,
                                      preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
                                         style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true,
                                   completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[Print Results Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIhA7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple's **[CKQuery Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/)**, you should be able to do both by using a tokenized search of the record's fields:

> To perform a tokenized search of a record’s fields, use the special operator `self`. A tokenized search searches any fields that have full-text search enabled, which is all string-based fields by default. Each distinct word in the tokenized string is treated as a separate token for the purpose of searching. Comparisons are case- and diacritic-insensitive. These token strings may be found in a single field or in multiple fields.

And here is the Listing 5 example (in Swift):

> **Listing 5** - Matching a field containing one or more tokens
>
> `var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self contains 'bob smith'")`

And the Listing 6 example (in Swift):

> **Listing 6** - Matching a field containing multiple tokens
>
> `var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self contains 'bob' AND self contains 'smith'")`

Finally, review the information on **[Indexes and Full-Text Search](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014043-CH1-SW10)**, as your record configuration in CloudKit affects which fields are searched (and performance).

---

**EDIT: Further clarification for your use case:**

Since you're using the contents of addressField.text to perform your search...

You have to decide whether you want a match to be:

**Option 1** -
When any *single* word in addressField.text matches any word in any field in a record.

In Swift 2.2:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self contains %@", addressField.text!)
```

**Option 2** -
When *all* words in addressField.text are in a field in a record (although not necessarily in the same order).

In Swift 2.2:

```
// creates a compound predicate to match all words in a string
// returns: nil if input was empty, otherwise an NSPredicate
func createPredicateForMatchingAllWordsIn(string: String) -> NSPredicate?
{
    guard !string.isEmpty else { return nil }
    var predicateList : [NSPredicate] = []
    
    let words = string.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    for word in words {
        if !word.isEmpty {
            predicateList.append(NSPredicate(format: "self contains %@", word))
        }
    }
    
    return NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicateList)
}

let predicate = createPredicateForMatchingAllWordsIn(addressField.text!)
```

If you'd like to do additional filtering, like only showing records where the words matched *in-order*, you can then do it client-side. (The CKQuery class supports only a subset of the predicate behaviors offered by the full NSPredicate class.)

Comment: Helps enormously. How did you get the swift examples? I can only see Objective C examples.

Comment: Also, my search variable comes from address.Field.text, entered by the user, so using your example 'Bob Smith'. So then I'm confused as to what the syntax should be for NSPredicate(format: "......???........")

Comment: I converted the examples from Objective-C to Swift, as this is a swift-tagged question. (Unfortunately, as you noted, that reference document only has Objective-C examples at this time.)

Comment: I've updated with more examples for your specific use-case. For more information on NSPredicate in Swift, see [this resource](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/).

Comment: let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self contains %@", addressField.text!) worked a treat! I don't know what you mean "client side" in this case ?

Comment: @ BreakingObstacles - So now I've added 'format: "self contains %@"', I can search all of the records, and its starting to work now, but i get these results back, which i can't explain..i've added a jpg of the print results, could you take a look? i am getting two sets of the same values back, just in a different order.

Comment: By client-side, I meant in your app. There are limitations to what you can do with CKQuery - sometimes that might mean you need to do further processing of results in your app (ordering, filtering, etc).

Comment: What's the code you are using to query and output those results? And what is the input you are using for the query? (i.e. the exact text/string) You may want to open another question because I think this is starting to get off-topic from the original.

Comment: I will start a new question, feel free to delete these comments..can we start a chat some where? I appreciate your help enormously.